# How to call a funciton from an another python file

Tags: django

I have a xml parser in python by named : NmapParser.py

```
def nmap_parser_sax(nmap_xml_file):
    parser = make_parser()
    nmap_parser = NmapParserSAX()
    parser.setContentHandler(nmap_parser)
    nmap_parser.set_parser(parser)
    nmap_parser.set_xml_file(nmap_xml_file)
    return nmap_parser
```

Now i have to call this function from an another file i.e. views.py. I did that

```
import NmapParser
nmap_parser_sax("/home/lovestone/Desktop/usoc/umit/nmap_example.xml")
print nmap_xml_file
```

I tried this it shows an following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "parse.py", line 2, in <module>
nmap_parser_sax("/home/lovestone/Desktop/usoc/umit/nmap_example.xml")
NameError: name 'nmap_parser_sax' is not defined
```

What i have to do is to parse the value from a xml file and then i have to save that value in my java script variable. I am on Django platform.

I also tried this :

```
import NmapParser
NmapParser.nmap_parser_sax("/home/lovestone/Desktop/usoc/umit/nmap_example.xml")
print nmap_xml_file
```

and still it is showing same error

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you either need to use

```
from NmapParser import nmap_parser_sax
result = nmap_parser_sax("/home/lovestone/Desktop/usoc/umit/nmap_example.xml")
print result.nmap_xml_file
```

or

```
import NmapParser
result = NmapParser.nmap_parser_sax("/home/lovestone/Desktop/usoc/umit/nmap_example.xml")
print result.nmap_xml_file
```

Comment: It shows this: 

    File "parse.py", line 3, in <module>
    print nmap_xml_file 
    NameError: name 'nmap_xml_file' is not defined

Comment: The only other place that name appears is as a local variable of nmap_parser_sax. What are you expecting it to print?

Comment: I want to check wether this xml file called out or not.If it it is so then i just try to call thaat funciton and print any value

Comment: You are not storing the return value of the function call anywhere. Should the return value have a attribute `nmap_xml_file`?